# URL query returns results in browser, but CSV export doesn't take in filters

Tags: rest, csv, url, sharepoint, servicenow

I'm trying to pull some data from a site into a sharepoint site using REST. The query filters work in browser, but when CSV= is added to the front it exports everything and ignores the filters.

This works
sysparm_query=company%3D9a641cf40a0a3cc201ef8ad1b4c88cf9%5Eoperational_status%3D1%5EnameLIKEPROD&sysparm_first_row=1&sysparm_view=

This doesn't
CSV=sysparm_query=company%3D9a641cf40a0a3cc201ef8ad1b4c88cf9%5Eoperational_status%3D1%5EnameLIKEPROD&sysparm_first_row=1&sysparm_view=

Answer (score 1):

For Web Service calls, the CSV is handled as a separate parameter. I'd recommend trying the following:

`sysparm_query=company%3D9a641cf40a0a3cc201ef8ad1b4c88cf9%5Eoperational_status%3D1%5EnameLIKEPROD&sysparm_first_row=1&sysparm_view=&CSV`

Note that I included *&CSV* at the end